# SQLite Table Doesn't Exist?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use a table from a SQLIte Database that I made.  I added the database server, that worked, I added the Data source and that worked.  No issues with that.  I've installed the ODBC, the Nuget for SQLite Core, I've added the VS extensions for VS2015 for VB.  I've added the table by dragging it from the data source onto the form, all of that without issue.  I run the program and I get this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information:

> ERROR [HY000] no such table: tblVisit (1)

I didn't add any code (as we aren't supposed to for the assignment). It's supposed to be easy to add it (as the second part of the assignment is to make the program using only VB Code, as a different program). Here is the code that I have from VB that was generated, if that helps.

```
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub TblVisitBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblVisitBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TblVisitBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet1)

        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.tblVisit' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
           Me.TblVisitTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.tblVisit)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I'm at a loss as to what I need to do.  Access, it worked easily.  I've been trying to do this now for three days it's driving me nuts.  can someone please point me in the correct direction?

EDIT: The table obviously exists, I can see it, I can open it in SQLiteStudio. If it helps, there is a red x over the database server in VS2015 even when it connects successfully?

Comment: Thank you @NateBarbettini for editing my post.l  It's late where I am at, I worked 16 hours today, too.  My mind and eyes aren't what they should be lol.

Comment: No worries. I've been there!